# Can I setup Eclipse to show code changes

Tags: php, linux, eclipse, svn

I have used Netbeans before with Subversion (SVN), and I liked how it showed me what I had changed since last commit, using the coloring in the left margin.

Can Eclipse do the same? I have installed Subclipse.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Visit Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Quick Diff, and enable

- Enable quick diff
- Show differences in overview ruler

Comment: The "Show differences in overview ruler" is unchecked in a vanilla Eclipse (Kepler) install - pity it is not on by default as it is so useful.

Comment: This worked. But when I save the file the colors disappear. How can I make the eclipse to show the diff between my local copy and the branch copy.

Answer (score 0):

SubVersive and Subclipse can both show changed files in the project explorer and differences between versions in the history.  I currently use Subversive and am happy with it (although installing it was painful the first time.)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem. It turn out that the SVN Label decorations in eclipse weren't enable.

```
   Preferences: General/Appearance/Label Decorators
```

This post helped me out:
[SVN-connected project not showing version info in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733492/svn-connected-project-not-showing-version-info-in-eclipse)