# Highlighting modified lines in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, netbeans

In netbeans, if I open a file which is under version control the lines which are modified are highlighted in the left. (green for new lines and blue for modified lines)

Is it possible to get a similar effect in Eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I setup eclipse to show code changes (I have svn)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942082/can-i-setup-eclipse-to-show-code-changes-i-have-svn)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

1. Open the Preferences window
2. Search for "diff"
3. Select Quick Diff
4. Change the "Use this reference source" to a SCM provider (like CVS, SVN or Git)

By default, it compares to the latest version on disk, which, if you've saved the file, is no diff at all. You have to activate the comparison against a SCM repo. I'm not sure what happens if you more than one type of SCM since this is only a single selection.

Comment: It seems that for Quick Diff to show git diff, the Eclipse project needs to be a git project. Otherwise, Eclipse acts as if you still have "Version on Disk" selected in step 4 above. So, to make it do git diff instead, I had to use "File -> Import -> Git -> Projects from Git" to create a project for the existing code directory. Source for this suggestion: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/331002/846869/#msg_846869

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan. OMG  .. what a beautiful feature disabled by default!  It's working for me for SVN/Subclipse in Eclipse. NOTE: Guys.. Don't expect full lines to be highlighted. The vertical Ruler/ Overview ruler shows the color you chose.

Comment: @supernova But if you click the ruler colours, it then highlights the text. Which is a bit naff, but vaguely usable.

Comment: When I type in editor or change something I can see highlihted lines with colors, but when I ctrl+s or save file - colors disappear. But I want them to stay while I'm not commit  diff, like in Netbeans. How to do it?

Comment: If it does not work, delete the project from the workspace (without deleting the files on disk), then reimport the project.

Comment: `You have to activate the comparison against a SCM repo` any idea how to do that ? Because when I save the file the colors disappear.

Comment: Note that unlike in Netbeans, if you enable this, unsaved changes do no longer get highlighted. So you cannot have both a Diff to the working copy and a Diff to the latest state of the repository.

Comment: If it does not work, try to close the project and reopen it.

Comment: Reopen your editors to actually see it in action.

Answer (score 5):

With Subversive, you can do Team > Show Annotations, and it will annotate the lines with the author and date of the last modification of that line.

Comment: Thanks. This is more or less what I was looking for. But it would be really great, if it just shows the diff between the current version of the repository and the local changes that I have made. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You can limit the annotations to a range of revisions. Selecting from the last revision to HEAD approximates what you may want (at me, HEAD..HEAD causes Operation failed).

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse by using its Quick Diff feature. This is easy to do:

1. Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors ->
   Quick Diff. This is the dialog from where it can be configured.
2. Turn on Quick Diff, by enabling the option `Enable quick diff`.
3. Choose the version control system for which Quick Diff is needed
   from the dropdown `Use this reference source`. Git, SVN and CVS should
   be present here. Mercurial appears if the MercurialEclipse plugin is
   installed.
4. The overview ruler is the ruler to the right of the scrollbar in the
   editor. If you would like to see the uncommitted lines to be marked
   on it, enable the option `Show differences in overview ruler`.
5. Choose Apply and OK. Close all editor windows and reopen the source
   file that you want in the editor.

You should be able to see the newly added, modified or deleted lines marked in colors in the left bar on which line numbers are usually displayed. The colors used are the ones set in the Quick Diff dialog (see above steps). You can also view these uncommitted locations marked along the overview ruler on the right.

Answer (score 5):

For ***Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)*** Go to

1. Select 'window'
2. Select 'Preferences'
3. Go to General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Quick Diff
4. Tick 'Enable quick diff'
5. Tick 'Show differences in overview ruler'
6. **If you want to keep the changes after you save your local copy**, then you need to tell the eclipse to compare the local copy with the repository version. To do that change the `reference source` accordingly.

   [image]

Answer (score 4):

`Right-click` on the file > `Team` > `Show annotation`.
A `brown` tape will appear on the left-side of the code (it represents `commited` lines), and the `modified` lines will be shown in `white`.

Comment: Is it possible to have Team annotations swhoing automatically when opening every file ?

Answer (score 3):

EGit plugin's Quick Diff does exactly the same as netbans modified lines feature.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State

Answer (score 2):

There are *at least two things* you must do to get revision-based change highlighting (i.e., ones that *do not* disappear when the file is saved) to show up in Eclipse's "overview ruler" when using Git:

1. Prior to import, make sure that `Preferences` > `Team` > `Git` > `Projects` > `Automatically Share project that are located inside Git repositories` is checked **or** import the project into your workspace using `Import...` > `Git` > `Projects from Git` (as pointed out by @cornelius in a comment on another answer)
2. Enable Quick Diff and select "A Git Revision" as the reference source: `Preferences` > `Editors` > `Text Editors` > `Quick Diff`

Comment: The part about import is parlty wrong. In most cases; project gets linked to Git even without using the dedicated import wizard. In case it's missing, doing Right-click > Team > Share on Git on the project makes the binding automatically.   About the freeze at import, please report it as a bug to http://bugs.eclipse.org with some steps to reproduce.

Comment: @Mickael Yeah, sometimes import from Maven does hook-up to git automatically. I have one Eclipse Neon install that correctly connects, and another that doesn't. I haven't been able to track down what the difference is.

Comment: Maybe Preferences > Team > Git > Projects > Automatically Share project that are located inside Git repositories?

Comment: @Mickael err... um... yeah. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse too you will get the line highlighted which is changed util you save the file. 
and highlight is nothing but the change in color at the left panel of the editor before the start of that changed line.

Comment: I believe the author is looking for a way to see what lines have been changed between project *commits*, instead of between file *saves*.

Comment: As Benjamin mentioned, I was looking for the changes between project commits and not between file saves.

Comment: sorry I thought between the saves. But anyways this is also useful for somebody who don't know.