# Find the just written code in a java file with Eclipse (i.e. highlight the new part of code)

Tags: java, eclipse

**Context**

I am modifying a big project in Java. In a file, I make some modification to the code (maybe inadvertently). The file is marked with a little `*` close to the name (that means it is still not saved).

**Question**

*How to find where the new characters were just written?*

I know I can use ctrl+z to undo the changes and, thus, find the place where the changes were made. What I am looking for is a way of highlighting the new part in the existing code.

Comment: are you using git?

Comment: try git? in all seriousness, is "right click" -> "compare with" -> "local history" what you are looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlighting modified lines in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447146/highlighting-modified-lines-in-eclipse)

Comment: How about  [Quick diff](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-cvs-quickdiff.htm) or *Ctrl+Q* (for last edit location)?

Comment: the git solution works as well!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse already shows this information by default. Every unsaved change is marked on the left line number ruler.

Deleted lines are marked with an horizontal line "-".
Added/changed lines are marked with a different color of the line number.

[image]

Comment: oh! I did notice it before!!

Comment: and, also, on the right side, if the file is very big, it is helpful to locate within it where is the portion of the new code! the colour is the same light red!