# SVN-connected project not showing version info in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, version

I've imported existing project from SVN repository, but it **won't show version information for the elements**:

[image: no version numbers]

That is **strange** to me because:

1. Import passed w/o an error,
2. The Team menu looks just like for
   normal, SVN-connected project.

[image: yet, Team menu is looking like the project is on SVN]

---

Here are my **installation details**:

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Are SVN Label decorations enabled in Preferences: General/Appearance/Label Decorators?

If yes, then check the settings at Team/SVN/Label Decorations.

Comment: Me too!!! It happened to me after I upgraded the SVN working copy to 1.7 and had to upgrade Subversive because of that.

Comment: Have the same problem.  Just turned the decorations (back) on.  Does anyone know how they get turned off in the first place?!?

Comment: I experienced the same issue once right after Subversive installation (no idea what has caused it) and once after a workspace crash (in that case it is possible that some preferences were written out badly). But in general, this should not happen, so I have no idea what happened there.

Comment: I had this problem. Thanks a lot! Fixed! +1

Answer (score 1):

GOTO  windows/preferences/General/Label Decorations/ and check SVN

and then apply , it will show the change list immediately .