# Eclipse - Showing changes before saving

Tags: eclipse

I run into this problem a lot. Sometimes I would edit and forget about it in Eclipse or maybe keyboard moved randomly and input random characters. How do I view current changes compared to the last save easily in Eclipse? That way, I would know what changes took effect before I save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either
`compare editor`-show changes between 2 or 3 files by showing each file side-by-side

*First select the files on the Project Explorer with `control-click`. 
Now right-click -> Select Compare With / Each Other.*

or

`Quick Diff` - General > Editors > Text Editors > Quick Diff

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see what lines have changed, then you can follow the instructions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942082/can-i-setup-eclipse-to-show-code-changes-i-have-svn) in order to show a highlight of the changed lines on the left-hand side of your editor.

Aside from that I don't think it's easy to tell what's recently been changed without saving. If you do save then you have the option of comparing with the previous version: right-click on the file in the tree and choose "Compare With -> Local History" and then choose a version you saved earlier.

If you save it you can also compare against what's in source control, of course. You are using some sort of source control?